# Разница между поступать и подавать?

Tags: значения, выбор-слова

Пытаюсь досконально разобрать разницу между поступать и подавать. Так, чтобы понял иностранец.

Предполагаю, что *поступать* описывает весь процесс подачи документов **и зачисления**. (Иначе как может получится, поступал-поступал, да не поступил?) А *подавать* аналогично *пытаться поступить*.
Однако встают вопросы:

- Может ли человек *поступать* туда, куда его точно не возьмут? Или
  только подавать?
- Может ли человек *поступать* в несколько вузов, если зачисляют его только в один? Или, опять же, только подавать?
- Можно ли *подавать* на лингвиста? Если только поступать, подразумевается ли обязательно, что человек в какой-то вуз да поступит?
- Аналогично, можно ли *подавать* на лингвистику? Или только поступать?

Comment: Разница тут в субъекте и объекте предложения  (экстраполируемого из глагола). Поступает - человек, подают - документы. Всё. 
А прилагаемые тут вопросы, на мой взгляд - не имеют никакого отношения к тематике данного места...   
__________
" поступать описывает весь процесс" - да.
а подавать - лишь процесс подачи документов.

Answer (score 2):

> Предполагаю, что поступать описывает весь процесс подачи документов и зачисления.

Ну да, так оно и есть. **Поступление** - это **весь процесс целиком**. Он состоит из нескольких этапов: подача документов, экзамены, конкурсный отбор, приказ о зачислении.

Т.е. **подача документов** - это **часть процесса поступления**. Первый шаг, совершив который человек выражает своё желание поступить в данный вуз.

Дальше пошло субъективное мнение:
Мне кажется, что употребление этих слов не зависит от ожидаемого успеха и от количества вузов, в которые человек пытается поступить. А само использование слова "подавать" в смысле "поступать" смахивает на разговорный вариант, сильно зависящий от контекста. Вот просто отдельно взятое словосочетание "подавать на науку (лингвистику)" мне кажется очень косноязычным, но может ему просто нужен какой-то особый контекст.

Answer (score 0):

> поступать описывает весь процесс подачи документов и зачисления.

I agree. Application and document submission, admission tests, interviews and enrollment are all included in the word *поступать*.

> А подавать аналогично пытаться поступить

No. *Подавать*, as you're using it, is an ellipsis of *подавать заявление/документы для поступления*, which is usually only a first step in the admissions process.

> Может ли человек поступать туда, куда его точно не возьмут? Или только подавать?

Once you submit your application (and other documents) for admission, you start the process. *Подавать документы* is a necessary part of *поступать*, so you cannot do one without another.

> Может ли человек поступать в несколько вузов, если зачисляют его только в один? Или, опять же, только подавать?

That depends on admissions rules and/or local laws, I suppose. As far as I know, currently in Russia, one can not only apply for admission, but actually be admitted and enrolled in multiple universities/colleges, or multiple courses at the same college. Again, *подавать (заявление/документы)* is a necessary first step for *поступать* so one cannot happen without the other.

> Можно ли подавать на лингвиста

You can certainly use this ellipsis when you mean *подавать (исковое заявление) на лингвиста (в суд)*. I wouldn't say that if you mean "submit an application for admission to a university".

> Аналогично, можно ли подавать на лингвистику

That would be a suitable ellipsis for *подавать заявление для поступления на специальность "лингвистика"*.